# Converting a Hex String to Ascii in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I've a query which fetches data from a MySQL database and displays in a table widget in Hex Format.

How can I convert the data and display it in Ascii Format.

Here is the Code:

```
ui->table->setItem(rows,1,new 
  QTableWidgetItem(query_ui_table->value("SHOW_NAME").toString()));
```

So,the value is displayed in table as it is taken from database.

EX: -00540065006c006500730068006f007000700069006e0067

Whereas it should display something like "Teleshopping".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [QByteArray::fromHex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex)

```
QByteArray text = QByteArray::fromHex("00540065006c006500730068006f007000700069006e0067");
text.data();            // returns "Teleshopping"
```

Comment: @nbb...Thank you for answer.using QByteArray::fromHex I'm able to convert a particular value.But currently my code fetches multiple data from a database.How to convert all of them?

Comment: Glad to help. You should consider up-voting and [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). As for your question, since the data stored in some columns of you db table is in hex I believe you will have to do this conversion for all the required columns.

Comment: @nnb...I can't upvote till I reach a certain reputation.And I need a code to convert all the data.If I do manual conversion for all data,which is hundreds in number,it will be a painful task.

Comment: Update your question with the current code you have and I will tell you where you will have to update it to handle this.